# Doctrine\ ORM\ Mapping\ MappingException in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

The full error that I got was:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                       
  Property "followed" in "BackendBundle\Entity\Following" was already declared, but it must be declared only once
```

when I was trying to make the entities at my BackendBundle.

I have 3 tables at MYSQL "empresas", "tecnicos", "profesionistas" and following have the fk of each table

```
CREATE TABLE following(
id int(255) not null auto_increment,
user int(255),
followed int(255),
CONSTRAINT pk_following PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_empresas_following FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES empresas(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_tecnicos_following FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES tecnicos(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_profesionistas_following FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES profesionistas(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_empresas_followed FOREIGN KEY(followed) REFERENCES empresas(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_tecnicos_followed FOREIGN KEY(followed) REFERENCES tecnicos(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_profesionistas_followed FOREIGN KEY(followed) REFERENCES profesionistas(id)
)ENGINE = InnoDb;
```

the code of `BackendBundle\Entity\Following` is

```
BackendBundle\Entity\Following:
    type: entity
    table: following
    indexes:
        fk_following_empresas:
            columns:
                - user
        fk_following_tecnicos:
            columns:
                - user
        fk_following_empresas:
            columns:
                - user
        fk_followed_empresas:
            columns:
                - followed
        fk_followed_tecnicos:
            columns:
                - followed
        fk_followed_profesionistas:
            columns:
                - followed
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    manyToOne:
        followed:
            targetEntity: Empresa
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                followed:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
        followed:
            targetEntity: Tecnico
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                followed:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
        followed:
            targetEntity: Profesionista
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                followed:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
        user:
            targetEntity: Empresa
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                user:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
        user:
            targetEntity: Tecnico
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                user:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
        user:
            targetEntity: Profesionista
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                user:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: Can you provide your mapping?

Comment: Please provide the code of `BackendBundle\Entity\Following`

Comment: let me edit the post providing the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to declare a ManyToOne relationship for 3 different entities. From the syntax alone it looks wrong that you should repeat `followed` three times.

I had similar problems before where I wanted an entity to have a mapping to X different entities using the same property. Something like this:

$person->$vehicle

where $vehicle can be an instance of Bicycle, Car or Skateboard (sorry, I'm struggling for my example here).

I don't think this is possible using doctrine and you might need to add another entity in between (e.g. $person->$vehicleOwnership->$vehicle) or use [doctrine inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)